# How to tell if threads were ever stopped during their execution?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say I have 4 threads scheduled to run AT THE SAME time.
But perhaps, the machine only has 2 cores.
As a result, only two of them, at most, can run simultaneously.

Or they could be in the situation where they run - stopped - then run, etc.

Is there any way to know for sure if a thread was put to sleep/paused during its execution?

Comment: ...this would be kinda pointless on any OS that uses pre-emptive multitasking.  Which is every modern OS.

Comment: Won't thread.getState() give the state of thread? and Thread.isAlive()?

Comment: @svasa well, then you'd have to CONSTANTLy checking ... I just want to know "after thefact" whether the thread was ever pre-emptived ...

Comment: Is it just theoretical question, or do you have a practical use case? For latter, can you explain it?

Comment: Don't forget that threads become stopped to handle syscalls and interrupts.